# How to define action inside form in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form

I simply want to add an action to a form and I am trying as follows:

```
{{ Form::open(['action'=> ['AuthController@login'], 'method'=>"POST",'class'=>'login-form']) }}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login not defined. (View: D:\server\htdocs\PMS\resources\views\custom_auth\login.blade.php)
```

I configure laravel collective Html. Whats wrong in my code?

**Update:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    function show(){
        return view('custom_auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        print_r($request); exit;
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        );
        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }else{
            return back()->with('error','Wrong Credential');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a file called `app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php`? Does it have a `function login` in it?

Comment: Yes. I checked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put your action inside an array when using `Form` helper so try:

```
{{ Form::open(['action'=> 'AuthController@login', 'method'=>"POST",'class'=>'login-form']) }}
```

And of course, make sure that a `public` `login()` method exists inside your `AuthController`

Also, do not forget to add this in your routes file, `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks for your time. I update and same error found.

Comment: Can you paste code for AuthController ? I wanna see if you have a valid login method

Comment: I updated my question and share the code of AuthController.

Comment: updated my answer, please try adding it in your routes file, see the updated answer